# Create FeatureClass in Personal Geodatabase and store data

Tags: arcobjects, c#, line, feature-class, personal-geodatabase

I have to create a new featureClass in my existing personal GeoDatabase.
And save some polylines into this featureClass.

How can i do it?

I need c# code to do this.

Edit: I have a problem during Geometry type featureClass creation.
Here the code i'm using:

```
IFields fields = objectClassDescription.RequiredFields;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldsEdit)fields; // Explicit Cast
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IField field = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.Field();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldEdit fieldEdit = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldEdit)field;
fieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape";
fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;
fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
fieldEdit.AliasName_2 = "SampleShap";
fieldEdit.DefaultValue_2 = "test";
fieldsEdit.AddField(field);
fields = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFields)fieldsEdit;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldChecker fieldChecker = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.FieldChecker();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IEnumFieldError enumFieldError = null;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFields validatedFields = null;
fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace)workspace;
fieldChecker.Validate(fields, out enumFieldError, out validatedFields);
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass("Test01", validatedFields, null, null, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, strShapeField, "");
```

I get this error:

```
The module of database management can't find the table or the input query 'GDB_DataChanges'
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: [google is your friend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000025000000)

Comment: Are you trying to do this manually, or with a script?

Comment: I'm trying with c#.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function I wrote to create a shape file with only one attribute "Title".If you change shapefile workspace factory intto personal geodatabase workspace factory it may work for you.

```
        IWorkspaceFactory ipShapeWF = null;
        IFields2 ipFileds = null;
        IField2 ipField = null;
        IGeometryDef ipGDef = null;

        #region Create shape file if you already have your workspace object skip this block and go to creating fields block
        ipShapeWF = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
        int idx = filePath.LastIndexOf(@"\");
        string strFileName = filePath.Substring(idx + 1);
        string strfilepath = filePath.Replace(strFileName, "");
        ipShapeWS = ipShapeWF.OpenFromFile(strfilepath, 0);
        IFeatureWorkspace ipShapeFW = ipShapeWS as IFeatureWorkspace;
        strFileName = strFileName.ToUpper().Replace(".SHP", "");

        #region Create fields object for shape file
        ipFileds = new FieldsClass();
        IFieldsEdit ipFieldsEdit = ipFileds as IFieldsEdit;

        ipField = new FieldClass();
        IFieldEdit2 ipFieldEdit = ipField as IFieldEdit2;
        ipFieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape";
        ipFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;

        ipGDef = new GeometryDefClass();
        IGeometryDefEdit ipGDefEdit = ipGDef as IGeometryDefEdit;
        if (geomType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint)
            ipGDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint;
        else
            ipGDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline;

        ipGDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = ipSR;
        ipFieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = ipGDef;
        ipFieldsEdit.AddField(ipField);

        ipField = new FieldClass();
        ipFieldEdit = ipField as IFieldEdit2;
        ipFieldEdit.Name_2 = "Title";
        ipFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
        ipFieldEdit.Length_2 = 254;
        ipFieldsEdit.AddField(ipField);
        #endregion

        try
        {
            IWorkspaceEdit ipShapeWE = (IWorkspaceEdit)ipShapeFW;
            ipShapeWE.StartEditing(true);
            ipShapeWE.StartEditOperation();

            if (geomType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint)
                ipShapeFC = ipShapeFW.CreateFeatureClass(strFileName, ipFileds, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");
            else
                ipShapeFC = ipShapeFW.CreateFeatureClass(strFileName, ipFileds, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTComplexEdge, "Shape", "");

            ipShapeWE.StopEditOperation();
            ipShapeWE.StopEditing(true);
        }
        catch (COMException cexp2)
        {
    //if any error 
        }
        catch (Exception exp2)
        {
    //if any error 
        }
        #endregion

        #region Clear COM objects from memory
        if (ipShapeWF != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ipShapeWF);
        if (ipFileds != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ipFileds);
        if (ipField != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ipField);
        if (ipGDef != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ipGDef);
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [IFeatureDataConverter.ConvertFeatureClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConvertFeatureClass_Method/0025000002w8000000/) method.  Here is a code snippet:

[Converting simple data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000028w000000.htm)

Comment: I have to create a featureclass in my personal gdb, and then load the plylines to this featureclass. How can i do it?

Comment: You will have to write the geometry using an insert cursor, this link talks about it and gives some examples, http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000049v000000

Comment: Thanks, but i have another problem during the creation of featureClass. I edited the main post. If u can check it please.

Comment: Have you defined the source and destination workspace?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it. If i don't declase any geometry type in the fieldedit it work, but i can't insert my polyline into that featureclass.